# Java. Selenium. File Uploading Another One

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

In my case, works below method. 
I use Windows now, but after writing some tests, want transfer it to the *nix environment. And some cool guys says that path must be abstract one.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("admin_offer_kind_logo")).sendKeys("C:\\Path\\To\\File");
```

But of I try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("admin_offer_kind_logo")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Koala.jpg");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("admin_offer_kind_logo")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/Koala.jpg");
```

It doesn't wants to upload the goddamn file.

```
@Test
public void FileFinding() {
    String file = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.print("FilePath:  ");
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Above code prints: `FilePath:  C:\SeleniumTests\FirstWebDriverTest`

Full path to my file in project is:

```
C:\SeleniumTests\FirstWebDriverTest\src\test\resources\Koala.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of one good man, found two working methods:

```
    @Test
        public void FileFinding_Right_One() {
        String file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Koala.jpg").getFile();
        System.out.println(file.substring(1,file.length()));
}
    @Test
        public void File_Finding_Right_Second
        File f = new File("src/test/resources/Koala.jpg");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use com.google.common.io.Resources to get the file from your resources folder.

```
String filePath = "Koala.jpg";
URL resource = Resources.getResource(filePath);
String uploadFullPath = resource.toURI().getPath();
```

Or refer the logic from [How to get the path of src/test/resources directory in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit)