# How to call a a file on test resource in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

In my `maven` project, i have a `driver/chromedriver.exe` in the `src/test/resources`.
I wish to find the path of my `chromedriver.exe` in my `Hook.java` class which is in the `src/test/java` with below code:

```
File file = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/test/driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
```

or

```
File file = new File(AppTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/test/driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
```

or

```
File file = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
```

But, all of them complains with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is an image of my project:

[image]

So, how can i get the address of my `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: Put it into the correct location. `src/test/resources/driver`...

Comment: try this: `File file = new File(App.class.getResource("/driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());`

Comment: the answer was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit