# In Java Maven project how do I upload file (photo) from resource folder using selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I need to upload an jpg image from my resources folder where I store my image. But I am unable to upload the image

[image].

How can I upload the image and test my selenium project? Any help would be great.

Here is the code given below, which is not working at this moment

```
// to upload file from resources
    WebElement chooseFile3 = driver.findElement(By.id("profile-picture"));
    chooseFile3.sendKeys("//src/test/resources/Profile_Picture.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem --> System.getProperty("user.dir")
it will show the location of directory where pom is present.
You can print System.getProperty("user.dir"), to check what is returned and then check form your path as below:

```
String imagePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/Profile_Picture.jpg";
WebElement chooseFile3 = driver.findElement(By.id("profile-picture"));
chooseFile3.sendKeys(imagePath);
```

Alternate would be to use, as it directly reads the file from resources, [How to get the path of src/test/resources directory in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit)

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Profile_Picture.jpg").getFile());
String imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
WebElement chooseFile3 = driver.findElement(By.id("profile-picture"));
chooseFile3.sendKeys(imagePath);
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still showing that invalid argument: File not found.                                
  String imagePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/Profile_Picture.jpg";
   driver.findElement(By.id("profile-picture")).sendKeys(imagePath);

Comment: check if the file path is actually correct.what is System.getProperty("user.dir")  returning. i assume you  are using mvn test to run the tests?

Comment: /SeleniumAutomationTesting/src/test/resources/Profile_Picture.jpg                    This is my path but it is not printing anything @Ishan

Comment: I think because you are using eclipse to run it as junit test, it is not working, you can use  File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Profile_Picture").getFile()); String imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();  -> to read file directory from the resources folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit

Answer (score 0):

To upload file from Resource folder

Step 1) Save image path in Variable

```
String imagePath =  System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\test\\resources\\Profile_Pitcure.jpg";
```

Step 2) To upload file use Robot Class

```
public void uploadFileWithRobot(String imagePath) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(imagePath);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

        Robot robot = null;

        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        robot.delay(250);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(150);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! but I want an easy way to do it.