# Spring ResourceUtils showing strange behavior loading a test resource as a File

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-resources

Java 11 and Spring Boot here. I have the following project directory structure:

```
myapp/
  application.yml
  app/
    src/
      main/
        java/
        resources/
      test/
        java/
        resources/
          smoke/
            file1.txt
```

I have some code:

```
File resourceFile = org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile("smoke/file1.txt");
String filePath = resourceFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

At runtime, `filePath` has a value of:

```
/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/app/checksum-tests/test-file.txt
```

When it *should* be:

```
/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/app/src/test/resources/checksum-tests/test-file.txt
```

Why is this? And more importantly, how can I use `ResourceUtils` or something similar in Spring-land to fetch a valid (exists on the file system) `File` to a test resource?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Spring Documentation for [ResourceUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html)

> Utility methods for resolving resource locations to files in the file
> system. **Mainly for internal use within the framework**. **Consider using
> Spring's Resource abstraction in the core package for handling all
> kinds of file resources in a uniform manner**. ResourceLoader's
> getResource() method can resolve any location to a Resource object,
> which in turn allows one to obtain a java.io.File in the file system
> through its getFile() method.

In the JavaDoc of [ResourceUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.java#L159) it says

> Does not check whether the file actually exists; simply returns the
> File that the given location would correspond.

So using ResourceUtils is not recommended. There are many ways to getting the files. You can use  Spring's **ResourceLoader** if you want spring implementation

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

And in the method you can use

```
Resource  resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:smoke/test-file.txt");
if(resource.exists()){
 System.out.println(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Or you can use ClassLoader

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(resourceName).getFile());
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

If you use Spring Boot then this should give a path with in the target folder.This is because the ClassLoader looks for the resources on the classpath. In Maven, the compiled classes and resources are put in the /target/ directory. That's why this time, we get a path to a classpath resource.
E.g. `D:\file-tester\target\classes\smoke\test-file.txt`